# Copy paste tool which allows Hotkeys for finite number of items

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I have a task where I need to copy paste the values "Yes", "No" and "N/A" into a [form](http://s14.postimg.org/3xvvh2wdd/copy_paste_problem.jpg). This has to be done on about a thousand pages, manually. I was wondering if there is a tool which allows you to map certain text to Hotkeys. For example I would map "Yes" to Ctrl+1, "No" to Ctrl+2 and so on ..

I am currently looking at [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/). The way I am planning to do it is to just use a single key for the primary paste Hotkey (e.g. just the letter P) and then pick the number of the clipboard selection I want to paste (e.g. P+1 for "Yes", P+2 for "No", etc..). A slight problem with this approach is that if I pick selection 3, it becomes selection 1 (because most recent selection) and I have to pick 1 the next time I want to paste that selection which becomes confusing.

If someone has an alternate approach which could save time, please share. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Depending on how the form works, I would try to automate all of it - but at least "ctrl-P" sending something like Yes{tab}No{tab}N/A{Enter} all in one go.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Sending Yes{Tab}Yes{Tab}No{Tab}No{Tab}N/A{Tab}N/A on Ctrl-P works like a charm. Thank you!